# How to inject a color into boxed objects?

Tags: color, boxes, programming

Consider the following MWE. I want to give a color (`red`) to the boxed object (`Hello`). Unfortunately, it does not work as expected as if the boxed objects are shielded. How to remove such a shield?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox\MyBox
\savebox\MyBox{Hello}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{\usebox\MyBox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there some reason the color can't go in the definition of `\MyBox`?  E.g., `\savebox\MyBox{\textcolor{red}{Hello}}`?  When you use `\savebox`, LaTeX is creating the box at that moment; the `\usebox` just prints it.  So your color commands won't have an effect, because the box already exists and is already colored as it was when defined.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii: Yes. There is a reason. I want to reuse the boxed contents in many places with and without color.

Comment: When compiIing the MWE, what I get is your expected result.

Comment: @Z.H.: What is my expected result?

Comment: `Hello` is in red.

Comment: @Z.H.: It might be a miracle.

Comment: Now I know the reason: with the same MWE, `pdflatex` and `xelatex` typeset different results. If you could switch from `pdflatex` to `xelatex`, the problem will not exist any more!

Comment: @Z.H.: Confirmed. I got surprised.

Comment: @Z.H. Color commands are not yet active in the preamble with `xetex.def`, see my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\savebox` is defined using `\sbox` and the latter is defined in LaTeX as:

```
\long\def\sbox#1#2{\setbox#1\hbox{%
  \color@setgroup#2\color@endgroup}}
```

The text argument of `\sbox` is wrapped in a group `\color@setgroup` and `\color@endgroup`, when package `color` is loaded:

```
\def\color@setgroup{\begingroup\set@color}
\let\color@begingroup\begingroup
\def\color@endgroup{\endgraf\endgroup}
```

Additionally `\color@setgroup` sets the current color that is active, when the box is build. This is on purpose, because also other properties are fixed like the font. A box contents does not change in `\textit` or `\textbf`, neither the font family or size can be changed.

Colors are usually implemented by specials, then the following definition helps:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sboxcolorless}[2]{%
  \setbox#1\hbox{\color@begingroup#2\color@endgroup}%
}
\makeatother
```

It is very, very important, that the argument is put into a group, here `\color@begingroup` and `\color@endgroup`, because `#2` can contain `\color` commands, which automatically reset the color *after* the group.
If an explicit group is missing *inside* `\hbox`, the reset color special would leak *outside* the `\hbox` and the `\setbox` statement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox\MyBoxA
\savebox\MyBoxA{Hello}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sboxcolorless}[2]{%
  \setbox#1\hbox{\color@begingroup#2\color@endgroup}%
}
\makeatother

\newsavebox\MyBoxB
\sboxcolorless\MyBoxB{Hello}

\begin{document}
  \textcolor{red}{Red \usebox\MyBoxA\ red \usebox\MyBoxB\ red.}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

However, this trick depends on implementation of color. LuaTeX has a concept of attributes, where color can be much more closer implemented to font attributes. Package `luacolor` implements this. Then the elements, characters are attributed with the current color, when they are created. A reuse in a box will not change this. Therefore with package `luacolor` the example will look different, both "Hello" in black:

> [image: Result with luacolor]

If you want to have more portability and flexibility, a macro can be used instead, where the control over the fixed properties is much larger:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\Hello}{%
  \begingroup
    \fontfamily\rmdefault % roman font, no non-serif or typewriter
    \upshape % no italics, small caps
    % but series (bold) or font size are flexible
    Hello% 
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \textcolor{red}{Red \Hello\ \textbf{bold \Hello} \textit{italics \Hello}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result macro]

This also works with all color implementations.

## A note to XeTeX

The color driver `xetex.def` for XeTeX defines the color commands quite late via `\AtBeginDocument`. That means the color commands are *not* fully operational in the preamble. For example, `\textcolor{blue}{...}` inside a box will not work either, if the box is set in the preamble. If the box is saved after `\begin{document}, the box will work as in the cases with the other drivers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox\MyBox
\savebox\MyBox{Hello \textcolor{blue}{World}!}

\begin{document}
  \textcolor{red}{Red \usebox\MyBox\ Red}

  \savebox\MyBox{Hello \textcolor{blue}{World}!}

  \textcolor{red}{Red \usebox\MyBox\ Red}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result XeTeX]

The reason behind this "odd" behavior is that `xetex.def` wants to allow the user to disable the stack color implementation (maybe needed in some rare cases) via `\noXeTeXcolorstack`.

Workaround to enable color in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\check@for@XeTeX@colorstack
\let\check@for@XeTeX@colorstack\relax
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, when LaTeX creates a box using `\savebox`, the box is created at that moment, and any colors are already assigned; so when you `\usebox`, the current color doesn't have any effect.

One option would be to define the box with the color originally:

```
\savebox\MyBox{\textcolor{red}{Hello}}
```

Another, more flexible solution would be to define a command that builds the box dynamically upon issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\makecolbox#1#2{%
    \hbox{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
\makecolbox{red}{Hello}
\makecolbox{green}{Goodbye}
\makecolbox{black}{Whatever}
\end{document}
```

If the contents of the box are the same, you can eliminate `#2`, and just hardcode the text in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *TikZ* solution. I define two macros:

- `\savecolorablebox{boxname}{content}` to define and save a colorable box.
- `\usecoloredbox[color]{boxname}` to use and to color a box.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newcommand\savecolorablebox[2]{
  \expandafter\newsavebox\csname#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\savebox\csname#1\endcsname{\textcolor{white}{#2}}
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=#1]
    \node[text=transparent!0,fill=transparent!100]{\expandafter\usebox\csname#1\endcsname};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
}
\newcommand\usecoloredbox[2][black]{%
  \bgroup%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myw{width("\expandafter\usebox\csname#2\endcsname")}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myh{height("\expandafter\usebox\csname#2\endcsname")}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myd{depth("\expandafter\usebox\csname#2\endcsname")}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1 * \myh pt / 2 + \myd pt / 2]
    \fill[path fading=#2,fit fading=false,fill=#1]
    (-1 * \myw pt / 2, -1 * \myh pt / 2 - 1 * \myd pt / 2)
    rectangle (\myw pt / 2,\myh pt /2 + \myd pt / 2);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \egroup%
}
\begin{document}
\savecolorablebox{MyBox}{Hello}
test \usecoloredbox[orange]{MyBox} test \usecoloredbox[blue]{MyBox}
\savecolorablebox{MyBox2}{Hello gg}
test \usecoloredbox[cyan]{MyBox2} test \usecoloredbox[green]{MyBox2}
\savecolorablebox{MyBox3}{$x=\frac{a}{b}$}
test \usecoloredbox[cyan]{MyBox3} test \usecoloredbox[red]{MyBox3}
\end{document}
```