# How to apply colour options to the contents of TikZ nodes when the content includes \sbox{}\usebox{}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, forest, logic, turnstile

Thanks to Sašo Živanović for helping to identify the problem which arises as a result of my trying to apply options such as `blue` or `text=blue` to nodes within [Forest](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest/) trees which include turnstiles from the [turnstile](http://ctan.org/pkg/turnstile/) package.

Normally, if I apply a colour option such as `blue` to a TikZ node, the content of the node is coloured, whether it be text or maths.

However, if the node includes a turnstile provided by the [turnstile](http://ctan.org/pkg/turnstile/) package, then the colouration only affects content before and after the turnstile. The turnstile itself is not affected.

If I use `text=blue`, only the content prior to the turnstile is coloured. Neither the turnstile nor anything after it is affected.

Outside the `tikzpicture` environment, however, turnstiles are coloured normally, along with their surrounding text or maths.

For example,

```
{\color{blue}
\[
  p \leftrightarrow q \sststile{}{} p \rightarrow q
\]
}
\centering

TikZ/blue:

\tikz{\node [blue] {$p \leftrightarrow q \sststile{}{} p \rightarrow q$};  }

TikZ/blue text:

\tikz{\node [text=blue] {$p \leftrightarrow q \sststile{}{} p \rightarrow q$};  }
```

produces

[image: blue and black]

Sašo Živanović has established that the issue here is not specific to turnstiles but applies to any content which uses `\sbox{}` in a similar way. For example:

```
\newsavebox\mybox
{\color{blue} This is in blue. \sbox{\mybox}{This is in a box.}\usebox{\mybox} This is in blue.}

\tikz{\node[blue]{This is in blue. \sbox{\mybox}{This is in a box.}\usebox{\mybox} This is in blue.};}
```

produces

[image: save boxes in blue and black]

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247849/how-to-inject-a-color-into-boxed-objects), to which I am also indebted to Sašo Živanović for directing me, seems related.

I am guessing from the discussion there that the `\sbox{}` is executed before the option `blue` or `text=blue` is applied to the node content, so that the active colour at the point when the box is saved is not sensitive to the options applied to the node.

Is this correct? Is the effect avoidable? And why does `text=blue` do something different? Shouldn't the effect of the `\sbox{}` be limited to its group, so that even if its contents remains black, following content should be appropriately coloured?

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{turnstile,tikz}
\begin{document}
{\color{blue}
\[
  p \leftrightarrow q \sststile{}{} p \rightarrow q
\]
}
\centering

TikZ/blue:

\tikz{\node [blue] {$p \leftrightarrow q \sststile{}{} p \rightarrow q$};  }

TikZ/blue text:

\tikz{\node [text=blue] {$p \leftrightarrow q \sststile{}{} p \rightarrow q$};  }

\newsavebox\mybox
{\color{blue} This is in blue. \sbox{\mybox}{This is in a box.}\usebox{\mybox} This is in blue.}

\tikz{\node[blue]{This is in blue. \sbox{\mybox}{This is in a box.}\usebox{\mybox} This is in blue.};}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a failing in the pgf colour support which isn't setting the current colour as understood by latex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{turnstile,tikz}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
{\color{blue}
\[
  p \leftrightarrow q \sststile{}{} p \rightarrow q
\]
}
\centering

TikZ/blue:

\tikz{\node [blue] {$p \leftrightarrow q \sststile{}{} p \rightarrow q$};  }

TikZ/blue text:

\tikz{\node [text=blue] {$p \leftrightarrow q \sststile{}{} p \rightarrow q$};  }

\newsavebox\mybox
{\color{blue} \show\current@color This is in blue. \sbox{\mybox}{This is in a box.}\usebox{\mybox} This is in blue.}


\tikz{\node[blue]{\show\current@color\show\pgf@strokecolor@global This is in blue. \sbox{\mybox}{This is in a box.}\usebox{\mybox} This is in blue.};}

\edef\foo#1#2#3#4#5{#3}
\def\resetcurrentcolor{\edef\current@color{\expandafter\foo\pgf@strokecolor@global}}
\tikz{\node[blue]{\resetcurrentcolor This is in blue. \sbox{\mybox}{This is in a box.}\usebox{\mybox} This is in blue.};}

\end{document}
```

produces a log of

```
> \current@color=macro:
->0 0 1 rg 0 0 1 RG.
l.21 {\color{blue} \show\current@color
                                       This is in blue. \sbox{\mybox}{This i...

? 
> \current@color=macro:
->0 g 0 G.
l.24 \tikz{\node[blue]{\show\current@color
                                          \show\pgf@strokecolor@global This ...

? 
> \pgf@strokecolor@global=macro:
->\xcolor@ {}{0 0 1 rg 0 0 1 RG}{rgb}{0,0,1}.
l.24 ...\current@color\show\pgf@strokecolor@global
                                                   This is in blue. \sbox{\m...

?
```

showing that when `\color{blue}` was used, `\current@color` is (the pdf for) blue however in the `node[blue]` case, although the text is blue, `\current@color` is (the pdf for) black.

This is important as `\sbox` does not "know" the state of the color stack maintained by the pdf backend or dvi driver it just sets the colour of the saved text to `\current@color`

The `\resetcurrentcolor` command doesn't actually set the colour (it issues no `\special` or `\pdfliteral`) it just redefines `\current@color` to use the stroke colour as last set by PGF.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would you say this is a bug or an inevitable feature?

Comment: @cfr bug as far as I can see

Comment: I guess `node[font=\color{blue}]` will do the trick. (Or `node[font=\resetcurrentcolor]`) (Or `nodes={font=\resetcurrentcolor}`)

Comment: What I do not understand is why `\sbox` sets the color again while it can simply do nothing and PDF readers will inherit the color?

Comment: @Symbol1 Would you or David like to answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338055/coloring-text-in-tree-nodes?noredirect=1#comment829195_338055 ? Zarko thinks it should be answered separately, but I don't think it would be appropriate for me to answer it as I'd just be repeating what is said here.