# \maxsizebox resets color in TikZ \node

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, adjustbox

While trying to fix an [issue in `menukeys`](https://github.com/tweh/menukeys/issues/16) I think I found a possible bug in `adjustbox`: It seems to reset the text color in the node. In the following picture all words in the first line should be red, but the content of `\maxsizebox` and everything following it is colored in the current color (i.e. black).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [text=red] {
      NODE:
      Before
      \maxsizebox{!}{1.8ex}{Box}
      After
   };
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\color{blue}
NORMAL TEXT:
Before
\maxsizebox{!}{1.8ex}{Box}
After
\end{document}
```

Comment: \minsizebox changes the color of Box but leaves After red.  Also, if you put \color{red} inside the node it works fine.

Comment: Putting a \bgroup ...\egroup around \maxsizebox has no effect.  I did notice that adjustbox uses pgfmath, but otherwise have noticed no common variable names.

Comment: I found an \xdef\@tempa and \xdef\@tempb which might cause problems.

Comment: @JohnKormylo. Thanks for your investigation :-)

Comment: Related to [a question I asked recently](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300423/how-to-apply-colour-options-to-the-contents-of-tikz-nodes-when-the-content-inclu?rq=1). I don't think this is really anything to do with `adjustbox` specifically.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't think it has anything to do with `adjustbox` in particular. You can reproduce without that. You just need boxes, I think.