# Xelatex, and strange textcolor behavior in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, color, text

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

Normal \textcolor{red}{Red} Normal

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {Normal \textcolor{red}{Red} Normal};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this in `pdflatex` gives the expected output:
[image]

But compiling this in `xelatex` gives the following strange behaviour:
[image]

The text following the `\textcolor{red}{Red}` seems to be defaulting back to black in `xelatex`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Not sure, but try `{\textcolor{red} Red}`.

Comment: That only changes the first letter ('R') to red. Again, `xelatex` makes 'ed Normal' in black.

Comment: This is a bug reported already in https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/362/ and regardless of XeTeX if I remember correctly.

Comment: Ah. Thanks! Until it is resolved, I'll resort to using a macro `\Normal{..}` or something.

Answer (score 2):

There are similar questions around, for example:

- [Coloring text in tree nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338055/)
- [How to apply colour options to the contents of TikZ nodes when the content includes \sbox{}\usebox{}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300423/)

The main question is that at the end of `\textcolor` there is a `\reset@color` which does not know what is the proper color to restore.

---

The problem evolves when [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer) comes in. Basically the story is as follows:

1. [graphics](/questions/tagged/graphics) loads `pdftex.def` or `xetex.def` according to the current compiler.
2. `pdftex.def` will define `\reset@color`;
   `xetex.def` will define `\reset@color@nostack` and `\reset@color@stack`.
3. [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer) redefines `\reset@color`.
4. `xetex.def` will decide whether `\reset@color@nostack` or `\reset@color@stack` will be the `\reset@color`.

Here **1**, **2**, **3** happens at `\documentclass{beamer}` and **4** happens at `\begin{document}`.

Now you can see a problem: for XeLaTeX, since **4** happens after **3**, `reset@color` is redefined to be a non-beamer version.

---

The following code illustrate the difference more clearly

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=teal}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\begin{document}

\frame{
    \tikz{
        \node[text=yellow]{
            Yellow
            \textcolor{red}{Red}
            What?
        };
    }
}

\end{document}
```

LaTeX gives

[image]

and XeLaTeX gives

[image]

Neither of them is expected. What we want is yellow. But reluctantly, white is better than black. And white is indeed done by the beamer version of `\reset@color` and black is done by the `xetex.def` version.