# Coloring text in tree nodes

Tags: color, nodes, tikz-trees

Please, consider the following simple example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm, preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.append style = {text=blue}
                    ]
\node {root}
    child {node {left}}
    child {node {right}
        child {node {\textcolor{red}{L} child}}
        child {node {R child}}
            };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Why text in `L child` node hasn't red `L` and blue `child`? Interestingly, if I change color orders:

```
child {node {L \textcolor{red}{child}}
```

then result is as expected: blue `L` and `red`child:

[image]

Comment: I think this may be related to a question I asked a little while ago about Forest. Let me see if I can find it ...

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300423/how-to-apply-colour-options-to-the-contents-of-tikz-nodes-when-the-content-inclu I think your question is the same, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @cfr, yes, my question is somehow related to yours in tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300423/…  . I test solution given in * Symbol 1* comment it solve my problem. However, the problem which I "rediscover" is, as pointed * David Carlisle* is the bug. Since, my question is not related to `forest`, maybe it is worth that you make an answer to it?

Comment: Tree structure is unnecessary; `\tikz\node[text=blue]{{\color{red}L} root};` will show the problem. Even more irony: `\tikz\node[text=blue]{{\color{.}L} root};`

Comment: You are right.  This is not specific to tree but problem of nodes as such. Accidentally I discover this at drawing of tree. I think that my question is solved by comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the question is voted to closed, I have something more than a comment:

Color setting in PGF/Ti*k*Z is done is its own way. For example in `node[red]{foo}` and `node[text=red]{foo}` the color is ultimately set by `\pgfsetcolor{red}` [1]. This comment is documented as follows

> `\pgfsetcolor{⟨color⟩}` Sets both the stroke and fill color. The
>   difference to the normal `\color` command is that the effect lasts till
>   the end of the current `{pgfscope}`, not only till the end of the
>   current TEX group.

To my best understanding, this is saying that PGF's `\pgfsetcolor` and the regular `\color` are incompatible. In your case, you should either stick to `\color` by setting `node[font=\color{blue}]` or stick to `\pgfsetcolor` by saying `node[text=blue]{\pgfsetcolor{red}L \pgfsetcolor{.}root}`.

[1] to be precise, it is `\tikzoption{text}{\def\tikz@textcolor{#1}}` and then `\pgfutil@colorlet{.}{\tikz@textcolor}` and then `\pgfsetcolor{.}`.